# security.xml to java config how to reference position="LAST"

Tags: spring-security

So, I'm trying to migrate to Spring Security 4.0.4 and use java config in stead of security.xml

How do I implement

```
<custom-filter ref="userAgentFilter" before="LAST" />
```

in java config

```
http.addFilterBefore(new UserAgentFilter(),LAST??)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "LAST" in Spring Security Java Configuration. Everything is ordered based on the Filter class. Instead, you can insert it after your last Filter. For example

```java
http
    .addFilterAfter(filter, SwitchUserFilter.class)
```